# First row of excel sheets field name displays as data not fields?

Tags: vb.net

I have problem displaying Excel Sheet Data in `DatagridView` Excel Sheets Contains first row as Field but it displayed as Data in My `datagridview` Control of my app.

```
Public Shared Sub Excel_Connection_sheet(ByVal exlFileName As String, ByVal sheetName As String)
        Dim strSql As String = "SELECT * FROM " & "[" & sheetName & "]"
        Dim connString As String = String.Empty
        If ConnectionState.Open = True Then
               connExcel.Close()
        End If

        If exlFileName.EndsWith(".xlsx") Then
               connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;'", exlFileName)
        ElseIf exlFileName.EndsWith(".xls") Then
               connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'", exlFileName)
        ElseIf exlFileName.EndsWith(".csv") Then
               connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Text 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;'", exlFileName)
        End If
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel
        oda = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, connExcel)
        oda.Fill(myDataset)
        Dim dt = New DataTable(sheetName)
        frmDbconv.dgvFile.DataSource = myDataset.Tables(0).DefaultView
        oda.Fill(myDataset.Tables(0))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to first row as header in gridview change property like this

```
 connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; 
  Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;'", exlFileName
```

In This String Change `HDR=No;` To `HDR=YES;`

Comment: Than you very much, it resolved my problem bro thanks a lot again SATSON